# Force Browser to send post data as ISO-8859-1 and not UTF-8

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, utf-8, iso-8859-1

I have to send an post request to a server (IBM z/VSE with CICS TS 2.1) who can not decode UTF-8 data.

So I have to force the browser or my javascript ajax post call not to translate to UTF-8. I already got it working that he removes the charset=UTF-8 string from content-type header by setting own contentType in jquery ajax call. So server already thinking that it is ISO-8859-1, which he can decode to EBCDIC. But with the german Umlaute I still have problems. "HALLÖ" for example. Because the Browsers still do the translation to UTF-8 before sending:

```
        let data = $('#customerForm').serialize();
        let url = "http://192.168.200.1:7080/cics/CWBA/mypgm";

        data = data + '&action=save&segment=cusadr&lfnr=01';

        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: url,
          data: data,
          contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
          success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);

            if (resp.code != "0000") {
              app.$data.errorMsg = resp.data;
            }
          }
        });
```

How could I do the post in ISO-8859-1??

Comment: Use a proxy on your server to change the charset and make the request

Comment: Would be nice to find a client-side solution. already played around with escape(). But not successful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realize this question was posted over 2 years ago, but it seems nobody has followed up to document the straightforward, simple answer. So here's the answer....

By coincidence it seems, on the very same day Andi S. posted this question IBM publicly announced z/VSE 6.2. z/VSE 6.2 and its accompanying CICS Transaction Server release (Version 2.2) became generally available on December 1, 2017. CICS Transaction Server Version 2.2 for z/VSE added UTF-8 and UTF-16 support to the CICS channels and containers API. The z/VSE SOAP engine and the new z/VSE REST engine inherit this support. There should no longer be any requirement for any intermediate conversion step.

While z/VSE 6.1 reached IBM's End of (Standard) Support on June 30, 2019, for those who are still running a prior release of z/VSE and CICS who are not quite ready to move everything to the latest release, it's possible to run CICS Transaction Server Version 2.2 for z/VSE alongside a prior release and to connect them up. Probably the easiest way is to have a pair of LPARs (or z/VM guests), one running the latest CICS release with UTF-8 and UTF-16 support acting as a "gateway," and the other, interconnected, older release running the CICS application programs. Then you can shift the programs over to the new, updated LPAR or z/VM guest as expeditiously as possible, but you don't have to wait for the older release environment to be entirely upgraded in order to support UTF-8 and UTF-16 interoperability.

Even if you're still running a z/VSE release prior to z/VSE 6.1, this "mixed CICS release" approach should work fine if you need it. (CICS has no particular interconnection limitations between releases and even between platforms as long as you are using one of the "lowest common denominator" interconnection choices that both/all CICS environments support.) Please note that IBM ended "Single Version Charge" limitations in early 2017. Double check with IBM of course, but there should be no additional charge to run two or more versions of z/VSE and CICS for however long you need to until you get your programs moved up to the latest releases.

Comment: We are on z/VSE 6.2 meanwhile. Still facing some problems with TS and UTF8 sometimes, but had not time to figure it out yet. At the moment i am using Channels and Containers to translate my UTF-8 strings into EBCDIC